# Issue Connecting to Cloud SQL Postgres using Private IP from GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, vpc-peering

Steps I have followed:

#### 1. Create VPC network

`gcloud compute networks create stg-vpc \
  --subnet-mode custom`

#### 2. Create IP range for VPC Peering for this network

`gcloud beta compute addresses create google-managed-services-stg-vpc \
  --global \
  --purpose=VPC_PEERING \
  --description="peering range for psql" \
  --addresses=10.20.0.0 \
  --prefix-length=16 \
  --network=stg-vpc`

#### 3. Assign Private IP to Cloud SQL Postgres Instance

In the Cloud SQL Web Console I create a new Postgres instance. In *Connectivity* options I enable *Private IP*, and configure it to `stg-vpc` with the IP range `google-managed-services-stg-vpc`.

This creates Cloud SQL Postgres instance with IP `10.20.0.3`.

#### 4. Create a subnetwork for GKE cluster

`gcloud compute networks subnets create stg-vpc-us-central1 \
  --network stg-vpc \
  --region us-central1 \
  --range 10.10.0.0/16`

#### 5. Create GKE cluster and deploy application that connects to DB in Cloud SQL

`gcloud -q container clusters create cluster-1 \
  --zone us-central1-a \
  --num-nodes 3 \
  --network stg-vpc \
  --subnetwork stg-vpc-us-central1`

I deploy a Java application that connects to the Private IP of the Cloud SQL DB instance using Postgres JDBC driver. I get the error `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`.

I also tried the additional steps:

1. I created a firewall rule to open the Postgres port for the IP range: `gcloud compute firewall-rules create psql-access --network stg-vpc --allow tcp:5432 --source-ranges 10.20.0.0/16`.
2. I was able to ping from inside the docker container to the K8s host machines, but not to the Postgres instance.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong, and why the VPC peering is not working.

Comment: How are you creating the cluster? Are you using VPC-Native pods? If not, you may need to [modify the IP MASQ of your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent). [GKE uses iptables to route traffic and excludes all private IP ranges from SNAT](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce) which you can change

Comment: I edited the question to give details of the GKE cluster creation command I used. I was able to successfully connect to Postgres using the [VPC-native PODs approach](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres by creating a [VPC-native cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) as suggested by @patrick-w.

My VPC subnetwork creation was modified to include two secondary ranges:

`gcloud compute networks subnets create stg-vpc-us-central1 \
  --network stg-vpc \
  --region us-central1 \
  --range 10.10.0.0/16 \
  --secondary-range stg-vpc-us-central1-pods=10.11.0.0/16,stg-vpc-us-central1-services=10.12.0.0/16`

And my cluster creation command was modified to enable `ip-alias`, and added details of the secondary ranges to use.

`gcloud -q container clusters create cluster-1 \
  --zone us-central1-a \
  --num-nodes 3 \
  --enable-ip-alias \
  --network stg-vpc \
  --subnetwork stg-vpc-us-central1 \
  --cluster-secondary-range-name stg-vpc-us-central1-pods \
  --services-secondary-range-name stg-vpc-us-central1-services`